Google Search Console reports "Page with redirect" as "errors", are they?
Many of my websites are getting that "error" from Google Search Console... It seems to me that a "Page with redirect" can be intended that way so the console should at least give us the option to say "that's what I want" rather than give us an error?!
That being said, I'm not too sure I understand when the Google Search Console decides that a redirect on a page should be reported as that error or not. It seems that it does not report all redirects. So there may be some other reason why we get those errors? Maybe an external link to said page?

The Page Indexing report doesn't say these are errors, but just lets you know the reason Google aren't indexing links it has found, so that you can review if there is an actual problem.
Their documentation advises the following

If there is an indexing error, or if a page was not indexed for a
reason that doesn't make sense, follow the documentation to understand
and fix the issue.


Decide whether there is a problem based on the not indexed reason and
your indexing goal, and whether this is something that you can fix,
based on the source value.

ie If there is an actual issue, try and fix it.  If not, that's fine.
It would be nice if they did let you check off pages and say "that's expected behaviour", but they don't.
If you are not talking about the Page Indexing report, please update your question to show where it actually says they are errors.

Ah. Yes. That makes sense. I guess they don't say "error," just "not indexed." This is good. Thank you for the references.
